# Troubles Saving tar.gz

Tags: 12.10, tar

When trying to package .tar.gz files from folders (backup) using this script

`tar -zcvf desktop.tar.gz /home/USER/Desktop/`

It's suppose to be saved as 'desktop.tar.gz' and its a copy of '/home/USER/Desktop/', but inside the .tar.gz the file structure is  /home/USER/Desktop/ instead of just Desktop/. Any ideas on how to make it save as just Desktop/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-C` option with `tar` like this:

```
$ tar -zcvf desktop.tar.gz -C /home/USER Desktop/
```

This will change the working directory of `tar` to `/home/USER` while running, effectively stripping out the `/home/USER` prefix of the paths.